# How to get `react-native link` to link my library via Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am writing a new library for React Native that uses native components for iOS and Android.  It depends on another native library via Cocoapods, and contains a `.podspec` file.  When I try to link it to a test project using `react-native link`, it successfully adds the source project as a library, but doesn't install the dependency via Cocoapods.

It looks like there are ways to customize the link behavior via `rnpm` keys in the package.json file, but I can't find any info on what those should be (it's also unclear if those are used by the newer link command, or are a holdover from the actual `rnpm` days.)  If there are docs on that that you know of, please pass them along!

Otherwise, my main question is this: how can I get `react-native link` to install my dependency via Cocoapods, or do I need to reinvent that wheel?

Thanks in advance!